# Android Room one to many relation empty list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have followed different tutorials and Stackoverflow post, yet I don´t get why my list of prices is empty.

I have two entities. Game and Price. Each game can have several prices.
Entity Game:

```
@Entity(tableName = "game_table")
data class Game(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val appId: Int,
    val name: String,
    val imageUrl: String,
    val isWindows: Boolean,
    val isMac: Boolean,
    val isLinux: Boolean,
    val gameUrl: String
)
```

Entity Price:

```
@Entity(tableName = "price_table", foreignKeys = [
    ForeignKey(
        entity = Game::class,
        parentColumns = ["appId"],
        childColumns = ["appId"],
        onDelete = CASCADE
    )
])
data class Price(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val idPrice: Int = 0,
    val appId: Int,
    val originalPrice: Double,
    val currentPrice: Double,
    val discount: Int
)
```

Relation between the entities:

```
data class GameAndPrice(
    @Embedded val game: Game,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "appId",
        entityColumn = "idPrice"
    )
    val listPrice: List<Price> = emptyList()
)
```

So far I think I made no mistakes.

GameDao:

```
@Dao
interface GameDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(game: Game)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(price: Price)

    @Update
    fun update(game: Game)

    @Delete
    fun delete(game: Game)

    @Query("DELETE FROM game_table")
    fun deleteAllGames()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM game_table ORDER BY appId DESC")
    fun getAllGames(): LiveData<List<Game>>

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM game_table ORDER BY appId DESC")
    fun getAllGamesAndPrices(): LiveData<List<GameAndPrice>>
}
```

The repository:

```
class GameRepository(private val gameDao: GameDao) {

    val getAllGames: LiveData<List<Game>> = gameDao.getAllGames()
    val getAllPrices: LiveData<List<Price>>  = gameDao.getAllPrices()
    val getAllGamesAndPrices: LiveData<List<GameAndPrice>>  = gameDao.getAllGamesAndPrices()

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insert(game: Game) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            gameDao.insert(game)
        }
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insert(price: Price) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            gameDao.insert(price)
        }
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun update(game: Game) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            gameDao.update(game)
        }
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun delete(game: Game) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            gameDao.delete(game)
        }
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun deleteAllGames() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            gameDao.deleteAllGames()
        }
    }
}
```

And the ViewModel:

```
class GameViewModel(private val repository: GameRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val gameList: LiveData<List<Game>> = repository.getAllGames
    val priceList: LiveData<List<Price>>  = repository.getAllPrices
    val gamesAndPricesList: LiveData<List<GameAndPrice>>  = repository.getAllGamesAndPrices

    fun insert(game: Game) = viewModelScope.launch { repository.insert(game) }
    fun insert(price: Price) = viewModelScope.launch { repository.insert(price) }
    fun update(game: Game) = viewModelScope.launch { repository.update(game) }
    fun delete(game: Game) = viewModelScope.launch { repository.delete(game) }
    fun deleteAllGames()   = viewModelScope.launch { repository.deleteAllGames() }
}

class GameViewModelFactory(private val repository: GameRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(GameViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return GameViewModel(repository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

If I´m not mistaken, I only have to insert games and prices normaly `ViewModel.insert(game)` and `ViewModel.insert(price)`.

But when I do `gameViewModel.gamesAndPricesList.observe(this, Observer { Log.d("onCreate", it[0].listPrice.toString()) })` it shows an empty list.

Comment: It will not work. There is no event triggered when you insert data in DB. The observer will always return empty.

Comment: Oh, do I need to create a ```@Inser fun insertGameAndPrices(gameAndPrice: GameAndPrice)```?

Comment: get a return from insert method and pass it to new live data. once the data is updated, use the obeserver there and call the gameViewModel.gamesAndPricesList.observe

Comment: Sorry, I don´t think I understand what you mean. Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed thanks to user **Sinner of the System** in the Spanish Stackoverflow [here](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/438553/android-room-relacion-uno-a-muchos-lista-vac%C3%ADa-en-relaci%C3%B3n/438680#438680).

The mistakes were made in entities column name.

Relation GameAndPrice:

```
data class GameAndPrice(
    @Embedded val game: Game,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "appId",
        entityColumn = "idPrice" // This is the mistake
    )
    val listPrice: List<Price> = emptyList()
)
```

The name of the field should be appId but it would generate another error due to having the same name as a related field.

This means that `Price` entity has to change the field value **appId** to **priceAppId**.

Price entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "price_table", foreignKeys = [
    ForeignKey(
        entity = Game::class,
        parentColumns = ["appId"],
        childColumns = ["priceAppId"],
        onDelete = CASCADE
    )
])
data class Price(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val idPrice: Int = 0,
    val priceAppId: Int,
    val originalPrice: Double,
    val currentPrice: Double,
    val discount: Int
)
```

And the relation `GameAndPrice` should be:

```
data class GameAndPrice(
    @Embedded val game: Game,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "appId",
        entityColumn = "priceAppId"
    )
    val listPrice: List<Price> = emptyList()
)
```